# Why doesn't LINQ work as expected?

Tags: c#

I have created a simple program to calculate primes as follows:

```
        var db = new HighScoreEntities();
        List<Int64> primes = new List<Int64>(){1};
        for (Int64 x = 2; x < Int64.MaxValue; x++)
        {
            if (primes.FirstOrDefault(y=> x%y == 0) == 0){
                primes.Add(x);
                db.Primes.AddObject(Prime.CreatePrime(x));
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

My issue is that `y` is coming out with 225 on the first go through and what seems like random numbers afterwards. Why isn't it iterating through the 'primes' list? I also tried using the Exists function with the same result.

Comment: Isn't this only looking for numbers that aren't divisible by a prime number as opposed to those that aren't divisible by any number?

Comment: First, if x = 2, then your formula is 2 % y == 0, which, as far as I know, isn't how you calculate a prime. Further, what's going inside Prime.CreatePrime() ?

Comment: @Reddog - that's actually a valid approach. checking for divisibility by composite numbers would be redundant, since any composite number can be factored into primes anyway.

Comment: And in your code, because the value of 1 is a member of `primes`, won't it always act as a possible divisor and therefore make every number end up in the collection?

Comment: @Reddog - correct me if I'm wrong, but any number is prime if it's not divisible by all prime numbers smaller than tested number. Otherwise prime factor would not work :)

Comment: @AndrewArnold - Right you are... Sorry, it's been a while since I took a  maths class. :-p

Comment: Not sure if you care to optimize this - but you are doing a lot of extra work checking all primes.  You only need to check up to sqrt(x).  Might be tougher to write that in linq, though. :-)

Comment: it's an entities thing.  prime.createPrime(x) creates an object of the prime type...  also a good point dmo...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 isn't a prime, so adding it to `primes` is probably a bad start. It looks like on every loop iteration you are finding the first element in `primes` such that the remainder of x / 1 is 0, which will always be true.

I didn't try the program out myself so I could be wrong, but that should be a good place to start.

Comment: the idea was to start adding to the database at 2, and it was to simplify things, That is a good point, but it doesn't explain to me why y is debugging at such a strange number

Comment: @Jeff - I'm not sure either, but I'd definitely start by initializing with `primes` at `{2}` and `x` at `3`.

Comment: @JeffLauder- is the code you posted exactly the same as you use? Because there is no way `y` to take value 225. I run your code (removed database related part though) and it never gave me such value, `y` was always only 1.

Comment: As per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number
> "The fundamental theorem of arithmetic establishes the central role of primes in number theory: any integer greater than 1 can be expressed as a product of primes that is unique up to ordering. This theorem requires excluding 1 as a prime."

Comment: I think it actually may have been my debugger, because while it was still giving me strange numbers, removing the 1 worked..  for anybody that cares, I also updated it to start at 3 and do x+=2, only really need to check odd numbers.  Thanks for the catch, I don't know why i didn't think of that

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the .Any operator

```
if (!primes.Any(y=> x%y == 0) )
```

Also there are many examples of using LINQ and PLINQ for calculating primes. [Here's just one.](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/11/performance-test-prime-numbers-with-linq-vs-plinq-vs-f/)

Comment: Yep, for this particular implementation, `Any()` looks like the way to go.

Comment: `Any` seems more natural here for me as well, however `FirstOrDefault` will do good job here also. If there will be any number meeting presented requirements, `FirstOrDefault` will return this number (and it will be different than 0) and if not, it will return 0 as default value for `int`. But you're right - `Any` would improve code readability here.

Answer (score 2):

First issue I see with this code is that `primes` list is initialized with 1. There are two problems with that number - 1 is not prime number, and 1 will always meet requirements presented in `FirstOrDefault` lambda, because any number modulo one will give 0 in result.

Apart from that, everything seems to be rather ok.